# Disable beans with build time property in my quarkus extension

Tags: java, quarkus, build-time, quarkus-extension

I am writing a quarkus extension. This extension includes a capability, which should be disableable by build property.

I accordingly annotated the beans of this optional capability with `@IfBuildProperty(name = "myProperty", stringValue = "true")`

In my deployment `Processor` class, I am adding the beans via `AdditionalBeanBuildItem`.

When using this extension in my project, the `ifBuildProperty` seems to be ignored, as the bean is still available even if `myProperty` is not set to `true`.

How can I disable a bean of a custom extension via build property? Can I somehow skip the whole build step that add the beans as `AdditionalBeanBuildItem`?

Comment: You likely simply need to make the beans of your extension discoverable. There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest would be to add an empty `META-INF/beans.xml` file to `src/main/resources` of the `runtime` part of your extension.

Comment: Simple as... That's it. Adding the beans via `AdditionalBeanBuildItem` apparently does not apply  `IfBuildProperty`. I still got to learn a lot about extensions... Thank you for your ubiquitousness :)

Comment: You are welcome :). I will add the comment as answer so future users can easily see it without having to read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to make the beans of your extension discoverable. There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest would be to add an empty `META-INF/beans.xml` file to `src/main/resources` of the runtime part of your extension.

Comment: This answer helped me immensely - even though I had a slightly different problem. I was trying to expose a REST endpoint as part of a Quarkus extension, but was missing `beans.xml`, which is why the endpoint wasn't reachable for the Quarkus app that used the extension. Until now, that is. Thank you so much!